# IE11 shows every { display: table-cell } element at a new line

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, browser, cross-browser

I have the following HTML ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AlexandrAbakumov/w6rc8x15/)):

```
<div class="form-group tabled-contents">
    <div style="display: table-row;">
        <input id="BodyContentPlaceholder_TxtCustomerId" type="text">
        <input id="BodyContentPlaceholder_BtnShowByCustomerId" type="submit" value="Show">
    </div>
</div>
```

And the following CSS:

```
.tabled-contents {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

.form-group input[type=text], .form-group input[type=submit] {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 200px;
}
```

It looks as expected in all browsers (Chrome, FF etc.): both `input`s are on the same row.
But in IE11 the second `input` is rendered under the first one.

Does anybody know why it's so and how to make it to be shown in IE the same way as in the other browsers?

Comment: Don't give controls like `input` and `select` and stuff other display values. Just don't. Put them in `span`s or `div`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I submitted a [bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedbackdetail/view/1263383/ie11-shows-every-html-input-element-with-display-table-cell-css-style-at-a-new-line) to the IE development team and it has been accepted as the issue.

I'll update this post upon changing the status of the bug.

Answer (score 0):

**Workaround**

add an empty div

```
<div style="width:0;display:table-cell"></div>
```

**Example** Codepen http://codepen.io/vinaymavi/pen/JWjxJb

```
<div style="display:table">
  <div style="width:0;display:table-cell"></div>
  <div style="display:table-cell;border:1px solid;">
   Cell-1
  </div>
  <div style="width:0;display:table-cell"></div>
  <div style="display:table-cell;border:1px solid;">
    Cell-2
  </div>
  <div style="width:0;display:table-cell"></div>
  <div style="display:table-cell;border:1px solid;">
    Cell-3
  </div>
</div>
```

For more info please check 
Microsoft bug https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedbackdetail/view/1263383/ie11-shows-every-html-input-element-with-display-table-cell-css-style-at-a-new-line#

Answer (score 0):

use the 'table' display property and the 'table-row' display property for the wrapping elements, but don't use the 'table-cell' property for the input element. just don't set the display property for those inline elements. and everything will work just fine, even in ie country :)
p.s. - wrapping an input element with a div or other element contaminates the semantic structure, it should remain simple and true to meaning as much as possible.