# display:table-cell not working in IE11 only

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11

So I just learned today that our site is not rendering correctly in IE11.  Works everywhere else just fine.  The issue is the second section that is set to `display: table-cell` is not showing up.  I found a bug report which seems to be the same issue here: https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedbackdetail/view/1263383/ie11-shows-every-html-input-element-with-display-table-cell-css-style-at-a-new-line

I tried the suggested work-around to no avail.  <s>My site is live, so no fiddle needed.</s>  My live site: http://clubschoicefundraising.com/  And here is the fiddle I created for when I get this fixed on the live site: https://jsfiddle.net/bo3khLjy/  In Chrome, Firefox, and IE Edge, everything looks fine.  However, the sign post on the right side is obviously gone in IE11.  Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Related SO post here: [IE11 shows every { display: table-cell } element at a new line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29748662/ie11-shows-every-display-table-cell-element-at-a-new-line)

Here is the relevant HTML:

```
<section class="main-content">
  <div class="tableRow">
    <section class="cell leftSide">
      <div id="drop-message">@Html.Raw(ViewBag.Message)</div>
      @{ Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Shared/_TopPartial.cshtml"); }
      @RenderBody()
    </section>
    <section class="cell rightSide">
      @{ Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Shared/_RightSidePartial.cshtml"); }
    </section>
  </div>
</section>
```

And CSS:

```
.tableRow {
    display: table-row;
}
.main-content {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.main-content .cell {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Here is the relevant code that the browser sees:

```
    <section class="main-content">
                <div class="tableRow">

                    <div class="cell leftSide">
                        <div id="drop-message"></div>
<div id="topPart">
    <!-- show this stuff at the top only on mobile -->
    <div class="row mobClubhouseInfo">
        <div class="col-xs-24 col-md-8 col-md-push-16">

            <a href="http://seller.clubschoicefundraising.com/Account/Register"><img width="250" class="img-responsive text-center center-block" alt="Clubhouse" src="/Content/img/ClubhouseLogo-NEW.png"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-24 col-md-16 col-md-pull-8">
            <h1>WHAT CAN <span class="orange">YOU</span> DO?</h1>
            <p>
                Join the Clubhouse (Seller Registration) – Each seller enters information about
                themselves and the fundraiser they are doing. Sellers must be
                registered in order to participate in special promotional contests.
                Once the seller is registered, they can participate in sending emails
                and/or text messages to family and friends regarding  their
                fundraiser.  Registration is easy! Click on “Join the Clubhouse”.
                Complete the required info* and you are registered!
                If you are already registered, click on “Go To My Clubhouse”.
                </p>
                <p class="fpNote">*(Don’t worry Mom and Dad, we don’t share this information with anyone. The information is used for customer service purposes only.)</p>
            <p></p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="signpost">
        <img src="/Content/img/sign-post.png">
        <a class="board board1" href="http://seller.clubschoicefundraising.com/Account/Register">
            <p>Join the Clubhouse</p>
            <div class="note">(Students Register Here)</div>
            <img src="/Content/img/board1.png">
        </a>
        <a class="board board2" href="http://seller.clubschoicefundraising.com/Home/Main">
            <p>Go to my Clubhouse</p>
            <img src="/Content/img/board2.png">
        </a>
        <a class="board board3" href="http://cris.clubs-choice.com/clbstatic/clblogin.htm">
            <p>Chairperson Login</p>
            <img src="/Content/img/board3.png">
        </a>
        <a class="board board4" href="/programs/referral-program">
            <p>Referral Program</p>
            <img src="/Content/img/board4.png">
        </a>
        <a class="board board5" href="https://shop.clubschoicefundraising.com">
            <p>Order Online Now</p>
            <img src="/Content/img/board5.png">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="startFund">
        <a href="/contact/contact-us">
            Do you want to start a fundraiser?<br>
            <img alt="Click Here" src="/Content/img/clickHere.png">
        </a>
    </div>

</div>



<section class="mainWrap">
    <div class="paddingWrap">
        <div class="clubhouseInfo">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-24 col-md-8 col-md-push-16">

                    <a href="http://seller.clubschoicefundraising.com/Account/Register"><img width="250" class="img-responsive center-block" alt="Clubhouse" src="/Content/img/ClubhouseLogo-NEW.png"></a>
                    <br>
                    <h2 class="text-center"><a class="text-center" href="/programs/contest-rules">Grand Prize Giveaway Official Contest Rules</a></h2>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-24 col-md-16 col-md-pull-8">
                    <h1 class="whatdo">WHAT CAN <span class="orange">YOU</span> DO?</h1>
                    <p>
                        Join the Clubhouse (Seller Registration) – Each seller enters information about
                        themselves and the fundraiser they are doing. Sellers must be
                        registered in order to participate in special promotional contests.
                        Once the seller is registered, they can participate in sending emails
                        and/or text messages to family and friends regarding  their
                        fundraiser.  Registration is easy! Click on <a class="join" href="http://seller.clubschoicefundraising.com/Account/Register">“Join the Clubhouse”</a>.
                        Complete the required info* and you are registered!
                        if you are already registered, click on <a class="gotoclubhouse" href="http://seller.clubschoicefundraising.com/Home/Main">“Go to my Clubhouse”</a>.
                    </p>
                    <p class="fpNote">*(Don’t worry Mom and Dad, we don’t share this information with anyone. The information is used for customer service purposes only.)</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <br>
        <div class="row">
            <h2 class="ital col-sm-24">Let our Experience speak for itself:</h2>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <img class="img-responsive" alt="Pizza" src="/Content/img/Pizza.jpg">
                <h2 class="fixed">Highest Quality Fundraising Programs in the Industry!</h2>
                <p>
                    Club's Choice stands behind its products and offers top-notch customer service to
                    our customers.
                </p>
                <a class="read-more" href="/step-by-step/meeting-the-products">Read More...</a>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <img class="img-responsive" alt="Eating Pizza" src="/Content/img/EatingPizza.jpg">
                <h2 class="fixed">Outstanding Guaranteed Services</h2>
                <p>
                    From day one until the day we deliver and beyond! All our products are 100% guaranteed!
                    If you're not satisfied, we can refund or replace your products.
                </p>
                <a class="read-more" href="/step-by-step/step-by-step">Read More...</a>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <img class="img-responsive" alt="Online Reports" src="/Content/img/phone-tablet.jpg">
                <h2 class="fixed">All reports available on-line 24-7</h2>
                <p>
                    On-line ordering, detailed customizable reporting and student generated e-mails, automatic FaceBook posts, texts.  extremely easy to
                    use and customer friendly online shopping experience and more.
                </p>
                <br>
            </div>
        </div>
        <img class="premier-logo" alt="Premier Choice" src="/Content/img/2014-Premier-Logo.jpg">
        <p>
            When you see the Premier Choice logo next to any product in our brochure, you can
            rest assured that it was manufactured by our family-owned business to the highest
            standards. The Premier Choice logo means we proudly serve it to our guests in our
            own home. “Your guests are our guests!"
        </p>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <br>
        <div class="row">
            <img class="col-md-8 img-responsive center-block" alt="Save-Around" src="/Content/img/SaveAround.png">
            <a class="col-md-8" href="http://clubschoiceholidayshoppe.com/">
                <img class="img-responsive center-block" alt="Holiday Shoppe" src="/Content/img/HolidayShoppe.png">
            </a>
            <a class="col-md-8" href="http://flash.clubschoicefundraising.com/TodaysFavorites-2017/">
                <img class="img-responsive center-block annes" alt="Auntie Annes" src="/Content/img/Auntie-Annes.jpg">
            </a>
        </div>
        <br><br>
        <div class="row">
            <a class="col-md-8" href="http://flash.clubschoicefundraising.com/RiverCity-2017/">
                <img class="img-responsive center-block" alt="Innisbrook" src="/Content/img/innisbrook.png">
            </a>
            <a class="col-md-8" href="http://flash.clubschoicefundraising.com/CookieDoughAndMore-2017">
                <img class="img-responsive center-block" alt="Otis Spunkmeyer" src="/Content/img/Otis_fund_logo.png">
            </a>
            <a class="col-md-8" href="/programs/candy-bars">
                <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="/Content/img/Hebert-Logo.png">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear-fix">
    </div>
</section>

                    </div>

                    <div class="cell rightSide">
<div id="rightbar">

    <div class="signpost">
        <img src="/Content/img/sign-post.png">
        <a class="board board1" href="http://seller.clubschoicefundraising.com/Account/Register">
            <p>Join the Clubhouse</p>
            <div class="note">(Students Register Here)</div>
            <img src="/Content/img/board1.png">
        </a>
        <a class="board board2" href="http://seller.clubschoicefundraising.com/Home/Main">
            <p>Go to my Clubhouse</p>
            <img src="/Content/img/board2.png">
        </a>
        <a class="board board3" href="http://cris.clubs-choice.com/clbstatic/clblogin.htm">
            <p>Chairperson Login</p>
            <img src="/Content/img/board3.png">
        </a>
        <a class="board board4" href="/programs/referral-program">
            <p>Referral Program</p>
            <img src="/Content/img/board4.png">
        </a>
        <a class="board board5" href="https://shop.clubschoicefundraising.com">
            <p>Order Online Now</p>
            <img src="/Content/img/board5.png">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="startFund">
        <a href="/contact/contact-us">
            Do you want to start a fundraiser?<br>
            <img class="img-responsive center-block" alt="Click Here" src="/Content/img/clickHere.png">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h2>Easy Fundraising</h2>
        <ul>
            <li>No Money Up Front.</li>
            <li>Pre-packed product by seller.</li>
            <li>Customized reports.</li>
            <li>Customized letters and thank-you notes.</li>
            <li>Online ordering.</li>
            <li>Email selling tool.</li>
        </ul>
        <h2>Most Profitable</h2>
        <ul>
            <li>Ordering.</li>
            <li>Free Pre-Pack per Seller.</li>
            <li>Free Prize Program.</li>
            <li>Free Brochures.</li>
            <li>School Grants Available.</li>
            <li>Invoice At Delivery.</li>
        </ul>
        <h2>Links</h2>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="http://pdf.clubschoicefundraising.com/order-form.pdf" target="_blank">
                    Download Order Form<br>
                    <img alt="Order Form" src="/Content/img/order-form-small.jpg">
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
        <footer>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        Toll Free 1-800-346-5599<br>
        <span class="yellow">You can now text us! 715-256-7662 (only between 9am and 4pm CST)</span><br>
        3421 Truax Court<br>
        P.O. Box 307<br>
        Eau Claire, WI 54703
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <!-- site seal is slowing site down, removing for now -->

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        © 2017<br>
        Club's Choice Fundraising.<br>
        All rights reserved.<br>
        <a href="http://clubschoicefundraising.com/home/privacy">Privacy Policy</a>.<br>
    </div>
</div>
        </footer>
```

Comment: Please include the compiled markup that the browser sees.

Comment: Don't post a link to your page. If you fix the error, the question will be of no value for future visitors. Include a working snippet of the problem into your question.

Comment: Good point @MatthiasS.  I added a fiddle into my question now.

Comment: Did you test my solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could solve the issue here. IE 11 renders actual width of images like "Hebert-Logo.png" - which has 1800px width. This was the issue here. I just added following css and it was working for me:

```
.img-responsive {width: 100%;}
```

Working version: https://jsfiddle.net//vybgc7rv/

Comment: That fixed it for me!  Thank you for tracking that down!

Answer (score 0):

In the bug report you found, and also in the related question, there was one workaround.

> Depending on your scenario, adding an empty `<div style="width:0;display:table-cell">` element between the inputs may be an acceptable workaround.

The stack overflow post also gave an example codepen: http://codepen.io/vinaymavi/pen/JWjxJb

See if that helps

Comment: I remember seeing that and trying it and never could get it to work.